# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/RxRelay.framework/RxRelay

Tags: swift, xcode12

RxSwift6.0.0-rc.1を
https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/tree/6.0.0-rc.1#manually-using-git-submodules
にある通り Gitのサブモジュールとして導入しました。

シミュレータとテストは問題なく実行できたのですが、実機で動かすと、アプリが起動した直後に

```
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/introspection
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/RxRelay.framework/RxRelay
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/836F14E5-6868-4C0A-A252-05AC0BADD121/hodai.app/hodai
  Reason: image not found
Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 6
```

というエラーがでます（ビルドは成功します）。

間違いなく

> - Drag Rx.xcodeproj into Project Navigator
> - Go to Project > Targets > Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries, click + and select RxSwift, RxCocoa and RxRelay targets

の手順も踏んでいると思います。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

carthageでの同様のエラーへの対処は検索すると出てきますが、Git Submoduleでの対処法は出てきません。
どうすれば、実機で該当エラーがなくなるでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

よくわかっていないですが、

https://qiita.com/fuwamaki/items/ce1cd438ec5dfd4ccb9a
を参考に（ほぼ勘で）

TARGETS から

`General > Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content`

にある `RxCococa.framework`, `RxRelay.framework`, `RxSwift.framework` を
`Embed & Sign`に設定したらエラーがなくなりました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

もともとは `Embed & Sign` ではなく `Do Not Embed` が選択されていました。